# How can I build a .ipa file from the .app file without a developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.6

I want to build a .ipa file from a .app file without a developer account, so that I can test my project on an iPhone or iPad.

This is what I've tried, but it has no result:

1. Copy the app to a folder.
2. Change the folder name payload.
3. Zip the folder.
4. Change .zip to .ipa.

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 and iOS 6.1.3.

Comment: You need a developer account as far as I know.  It is pretty locked down.

Comment: i do not have this account.i am a beginner ios programmer.

Comment: You don't need to be an expert programmer or even a programmer at all to get one, it's only $99.

Comment: my device is jailbreak It makes a difference?

Comment: If by, do I still need to pay $99 to get an app on there, I am not sure.  As far as I know, you need to have valid certificates to put apps on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Apple uses code signing to guarantee that only authorised iOS device can run an application.
So in end effect you can only test application on devices which are associated with an iOS developer program and when you have a developer certificate also from the developer program.
Testing your iOS apps in the iOS simulator is however free.

Comment: its right but i test app on real device.if my device is jailbreak It makes a difference?

Comment: You are unlikely to get much advice from the black hat jailbreak community here on Stackoverflow. I don't know if there is a vibrant community of black hat developers out there, but I'm pretty certain it isn't this one. I'd highly recommend you pay apple the $99/yr and join all of us on the light side.

Comment: I think it would be possible to run unsigned ipa's on a jailbroken device. However if you plan to develop more seriously, than I would advice to enter the iOS developer program. Per program you can register up to 100 devices and have multiple developers. So you can also share the cost with friends if they're up to it.